# Error when using polyglossia, french and make4ht

Tags: polyglossia, make4ht

A memory error occurs when using the package `polyglossia`, setting `french` as default language and compiling with `make4ht`.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\title{Test: 123}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    14   TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

I'm compiling with

```
make4ht -u -x test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht uses some tricks to support Unicode input. In XeLaTeX, it makes most of characters active. The active characters are then used to insert `\special` commands with instructions for Unicode. It seems to clash with Polyglossia in this case, as you can see from the full error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\nobreakspace ...l {t4ht@+\string &{35}x00A0{59}}x
```

The problem is that Polyglossia with XeTeX makes some characters active as well. Somehow it results in memory overflow. In your case the problem is with colon in your title `\title{Test: 123}`.

To fix that, we must redefine `\nobreakspace` at the moment when Polyglossia defines active characters, which is done by the `\french@punctuation` command.

Save the following code as `gloss-french.4ht`:

```
\pend:def\french@punctuation{\bgroup\let\nobreakspace\space}
\append:def\french@punctuation{\egroup}
\endinput
```

This file is loaded automatically by TeX4ht when you use Polyglossia with French.
The `\pend:def` command executes code before the redefined command, `\append:def` executes it after command ends.

Your example then compiles without errors:

[image]